# Why is my Bootstrap row not aligned well?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

Part of my goal is to make a grid layout similar to the image shown below, but it seems like my code doesn't do the job as the row was placed on a different line.

[bootstrap-row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrHR0.png)

This is what I've done so far. Can anyone point me out what I did wrong?

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; height: 400px;">
    <div class="col-md-6 py-5">
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656792566083-80e5dd4995f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="Card image cap" width="250" height="150">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: every .col should be wrapped by .row, and don't do row>row, or col>col. it should be always row>col, or row>col>row>col...

Answer (score 0):

Every column needs to be inside a `<div class="row">` so I wrapped the outer columns with one.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; height: 400px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 py-5">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656792566083-80e5dd4995f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="Card image cap" width="250" height="150">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
            bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
            bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
              bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little
              bit longer.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```